# Understanding X-Path Expression

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to get an understanding of XPath in order to parse a [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/) file. I skimmed over the w3schools site. Am I understanding these correctly?

Statement 1: `/node()[1]/node()[3]`

Selects the third child of the root node

Statement 2: `/node()[1]/node()[1]/node()[1]`

Selects the child of the first node of the root node

Statement 3: `/node()[1]/node()[3]/node()[2]`

Selects the second child of the third node under the root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand them correctly, but this is not how you'd use XPath. First `node()` can be anything, not just elements. Then the pure index is arguably the wort way of selecting things, you should really use names, and possibly predicates for filtering the node-sets.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to use xpath in this instance, just parse a file that outputs it. I agree with you but I think diffxml only outputs using pure indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a lot of criticism of w3schools on this site. Personally I find it a useful resource, but only when I'm trying to remind myself of something I once knew. It's not really designed for teaching yourself things from scratch, and I suggest you need a different learning strategy. Call me old-fashioned, but when I'm learning a new technology I find there's nothing better than a good book.

You've understood your examples correctly as far as I can tell. But have you understood what a "node" is? For example, do you know under what circumstances whitespace text counts as a node? The key to understanding XPath is to understand the data model, and the way in which the data model relates to the lexical (angle-bracket) form of the XML.